# Stokes Formula with wedge product

Tags: calculus, manifolds

$$\alpha=\sum^m_{i=1} x^idx^1\land...\widehat {dx^i} ...\land dx^m$$
Compute ${\int_S}_{m-1} j^*\alpha$ where $j$ is the inclusion map of $S_{m-1}$ in $\mathbb R^m$.

I'm mostly an intuitionistic proof or even fuzzy logic prover with incomplete fundamentals in differential equations, so I haven't come across calculating Stokes Formula, although I have it in this differential manifolds book where I got this problem.

Comment: *Hint*: Note that $\mathrm{d}\alpha=0$ if $m$ is even and $=\mathrm{d}x^{123\dots m}$ if $m$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**
$\mathbb{S}^{m-1}$ is the boundary of $\mathbb{B}^m \subset \mathbb{R}^m$. If $j : \mathbb{S}^{m-1} \to \mathbb{B}^m$ is the inclusion map, Stokes' formula says that :
$$
\int_{\partial \mathbb{B}^m}j^*\alpha = \int_{\mathbb{B}^m} \mathrm{d}\alpha.
$$
Thus, you are left to compute $\mathrm{d}\alpha$ and the integral.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your attention, this is the formula in the book, but I was wondering about, since you said, $d\alpha$ and the integral.  Does the comment above prove?

Comment: I may have a "low-working memory" compared to some advanced students, so I haven't been able to "chunk" most of calculus.  It's much easier to work spatially like on manifolds.

Comment: Just use the definition $\mathrm{d} (f \omega) = \mathrm{d}f \wedge \omega + f \mathrm{d}\omega$ if $f$ is a function and $\omega$ a differential form, the relation $\mathrm{d}^2=0$ and the property $\mathrm{d}x^i \wedge \mathrm{d}x^j = - \mathrm{d}x^j \wedge \mathrm{d}x^i$. It may seem long but it will clearly be instructive. Then, wheck the definition of the integral of $\mathrm{d}x^1\wedge \cdots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^n$ over a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in your book: you will see what happens.

Comment: What I see is $(d,f,\omega)$: an exterior derivative with a normal function and differential form having transitive-like group action.  Also, a nullary operation and an anti-commutative operation. Finally, wedge product set of $dx^i$ in subset of $\mathbb R^n$.  I know I probably shouldn't expect to see integers as solutions, but I don't see how these all go together.

Comment: Take $f = x^i$ (the coordinate function), $\omega = \mathrm{d}x^1\wedge \cdots \wedge \hat{\mathrm{d}x^i}\wedge\cdots\wedge \mathrm{d}x^n$, apply what I said above like it was an algorithm, and sum over $i$.